# have some tag inside anchor tag and text-indent not working

Tags: html, css

I have created  tag inside of  tag and applied text indent:-9999px; but its not working

for ADA compliance, We need to add (new window) text inside the anchor tag but i dont want to show the text so i used text-indent

HTML:

```
<a href="#" target="_blank" title="">Privacy Notice<em class="textIndent">(new window)</em></a>
```

CSS:

```
.textIndent { text-indent: -9999px; display: block; }
```

i would like to hide the  tag's text without using display:none or visibility

Comment: well, your solution should work. -> https://jsfiddle.net/nLzuvpjr/

Comment: Its working but additional space is coming below the anchor tag

Comment: and also i was using these kind for navigation bar also so its breaking and missing some alignment

Comment: Oh. You should be more specific about your problem next time. `I have created tag inside of tag and applied text indent:-9999px; but its not working` From your question we understood that the element does not get hidden. The 'additional space'  was because of `display:block` style . You should research to see what that does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To handle such compliances I prefer not to make the DOM dirty instead, a clean approach would be to add a new element with the required warning message and assign id to that element. No add the `aria-describedby` attribute, setting its value to the appropriate id of the message to be announced.
basic reference of how it can be done:

```
<a href="#" target="_blank" aria-describedby="new-win-52" class="" title="link">External Link</a>
<span hidden="" id="new-win-52">Opens in new window</span>
```

Comment: Thank you for your useful information. I have another doubt if I am going to open pdf document from the anchor tag how i have to write the tag (Web accessibility says need to mention the pdf on link like <a href="x.pdf">Profile PDF</a>) but i dont want to write PDF on link

Answer (score 0):

you can use `font-size: 0;` instead of `text-indent: -9999px;`

```css
.textIndent { 
  font-size: 0;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" target="_blank" title="">Privacy Notice<em class="textIndent">(new window)</em></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

> i would also suggest using these css, instead of text-indent:indent:-9999px;

```
a {
text-indent: 100%; 
white-space: nowrap; 
overflow: hidden;
```

}